# CentOS 7 Vagrant VM partially losing network connectivity

Tags: centos, vagrant

I am using a self-built Vagrant base box running a minimal installation of CentOS 7 (I created it following Vagrant's documentation - if you want more information, I outlined the process in an article on my website and you can download the machine from here).

Before provisioning the machine with Ansible (which is irrelevant for this question) I use the following Vagrantfile to bring up the box:

```
Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "relativkreativ/centos-7-minimal"
  config.vm.network "public_network", ip: "192.168.0.100", bridge: 'en0: WLAN (AirPort)'

  config.vm.provision "file", source: "~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub", destination: "~/id_rsa.pub"
  config.vm.provision "shell", inline: <<-END.gsub(/^\s{4}/, '')
    mkdir -m 0700 /root/.ssh
    mv /home/vagrant/id_rsa.pub /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
    chmod 0600 /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
    chown root:root /root/.ssh/authorized_keys
  END
end
```

Nothing fancy here, just adding an additional network interface and copying my public key.

When logging in to the server as root (`ssh root@192.168.0.100`) I *sometimes* get a broken pipe after a few seconds and the server is not pingable (sometimes even while running the Ansible manifest). Most of the time I am able to reconnect after a few tries but when this is not possible, I have to use Vagrant to login (`vagrant ssh` - this always works) and restart the network service (`systemctl restart network.service`). After that, SSH mostly works again for some time.

The server's routes:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ip route
default via 10.0.2.2 dev enp0s3 
10.0.2.0/24 dev enp0s3  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.0.2.15 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s3  scope link  metric 1002 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s8  scope link  metric 1003 
192.168.0.0/24 dev enp0s8  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.100
```

The network interfaces:

```
[root@localhost ~]# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:c0:9e:5b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic enp0s3
       valid_lft 84324sec preferred_lft 84324sec
3: enp0s8: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:b6:45:8c brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.100/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global enp0s8
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Their configuration files:

```
[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-lo 
DEVICE=lo
IPADDR=127.0.0.1
NETMASK=255.0.0.0
NETWORK=127.0.0.0
# If you're having problems with gated making 127.0.0.0/8 a martian,
# you can change this to something else (255.255.255.255, for example)
BROADCAST=127.255.255.255
ONBOOT=yes
NAME=loopback

[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3
HWADDR="08:00:27:C0:9E:5B"
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="dhcp"
DEFROUTE="yes"
PEERDNS="yes"
PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
IPV6INIT="yes"
IPV6_AUTOCONF="yes"
IPV6_DEFROUTE="yes"
IPV6_PEERDNS="yes"
IPV6_PEERROUTES="yes"
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
NAME="enp0s3"
UUID="957d70e5-1097-4952-b3a4-dc67b919b934"
ONBOOT="yes"

[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s8
#VAGRANT-BEGIN
# The contents below are automatically generated by Vagrant. Do not modify.
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=192.168.0.100
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
DEVICE=enp0s8
PEERDNS=no
#VAGRANT-END
```

I disabled IPv6 for troubleshooting but this did not make a difference.

This also happens when I run the exact same workflow with my CentOS 6 Vagrant box (which I built in the exact same way), and also with Vagrant boxes other people built.

I am using the latest version of Vagrant (1.7.2) as well as VirtualBox (4.3.20). I did not change anything on VirtualBox' default network configuration.

Does anybody have any clue what is going on here? I cannot track this problem down.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Exactly how are you trying to network this on the host?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked to disable the NetworkManager when I had the same problem (but with host-only network)

Comment: If you could explain how to do that, this would be a better answer. Please [edit] your post. Thanks!